# Приведение элементов гетерогенной коллекции типов к object в конструкции foreach

Tags: c#, объекты

Хочется реализовать перебор элементов коллекции разных типов в цикле foreach, с целью вызова одноимённого метода в них. Типы без проблем загоняются в коллекцию, но при вызове foreach срабатывает NullReference. Вот классы типов и класс основной коллекции:

```
// Тип 1
class MyType_1
{
    int money;
    string name;

    public MyType_1()
    {
        money = 1020;
        name = "MyType1";
    }

    public void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Это: {0}. У него есть деньги: {1}", name, money);
    }
}

// Тип 2
class MyType_2
{
    double money;
    string name;
    int id;

    public MyType_2()
    {
        money = 2.68;
        name = "MyType2";
        id = 1;
    }

    public void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Это: {0}. У него есть деньги: {1} и id: {2}", name, money, id);
    }
}

// Тип 3
class MyType_3
{
    int money;
    string name;
    string lastName;

    public MyType_3()
    {
        money = 4000;
        name = "MyType3";
        lastName = ".MyLastNameType3";
    }

    public void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Это: {0}. У него есть деньги: {1} и lastname: {2}", name, money, lastName);
    }
}
```

класс коллекции этих типов:

```
// Коллекция
class MyCollect : IEnumerable
{
    List<object> collect = new List<object>();
    int count = 0;
    int position = -1;

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (position < count - 1)
        {
            position++;
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
            Reset();
            return false;
        }
    }

    void Reset()
    {
        position = -1;
    }

    public object Current
    {
        get
        {
            return this.collect[position];
        }
    }

    public void Add(object value)
    {
        this.collect.Add((object)value);
        this.count++;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this as IEnumerator;
    }
}
```

В самой программе я создаю по экземпляру каждого типа и загоняю их в коллекцию:

```
// Три неких разных типа
        MyType_1 type1 = new MyType_1();
        MyType_2 type2 = new MyType_2();
        MyType_3 type3 = new MyType_3();

        // Загоняем их в коллекцию через инициализатор 
        MyCollect collect = new MyCollect() { type1, type2, type3 };
```

но при вызове перебора foreach, сразу после возвращения Enumerator срабатывает NullReferenceException.

```
// Вот тут ругается
foreach (object obj in collect)
            {
                Type t = obj.GetType();
                MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod("Method", BindingFlags.Instance);
                mi.Invoke(t, null);
            }
```

Может кто-то сталкивался с подобным, и подскажет в каком месте я подаю ссылку на несуществующий элемент?

Comment: "this as IEnumerator;" - так делать нельзя. Этот каст всегда даст null, подумайте сами почему. Отсюда и NRE при перечислении коллекции.

Comment: Не раз использовал подобный подход, работало. Foreach требует реализации метода GetEnumerator(). Прокатывало с коллекциями объектов, но не типов. Ругань начинается на слове "in" в объявлении условий цикла foreach. Может быть это связано с тем что разные типы ельзя привести к object&

Comment: «Не раз использовал подобный подход» — ну, то, что какой-то код раньше работал, не значит же, что он правильный в любой ситуации? И да, зачем вам рефлексия?

Comment: @VladD, потому что IEnumerator не generic

Comment: @VladD, в отсутствии мысли о общем интерфейсе для типов, нужно было найти способ реализовать одноимённый каждого типа

Comment: @Garrus_En: А почему у типов есть одинаково называемый метод, но нет общего интерфейса? (Можно использовать было бы, например, `dynamic`, хотя будет по идее не быстрее.)

Comment: @Garrus_En: Ещё, а зачем вам кастомная коллекция? Чем просто `System.Collections.List` (необобщённый) или тот же `List<object>` не подходят?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MyCollect не реализует интерфейс IEnumerator, напишите так

```
class MyCollect : IEnumerable, IEnumerator
{
     ...
}
```

А вообще, чтобы не пользоваться рефлексией, реализуйте один общий интерфейс, например

```
interface IMyType
{
     void Method();
}

class MyType_1 : IMyType
{
...
}

class MyType_2 : IMyType
{
...
}

class MyType_3 : IMyType
{
...
}

class MyCollect : IEnumerable<IMyType>, IEnumerator
{
...
}

foreach (IMyType obj in collect)
{
    obj.Method();
}
```

Comment: Получается что одноимённого метода для foreach недостаточно, необходимо обязательно реализовать iEnumerator?

Comment: @Garrus_En: `IEnumerator` должен быть реализован _где-то_, не обязательно в том же классе. Раз у вас он не реализован, подумайте, что вернёт `this as IEnumerator`.

Comment: @Garrus_En достаточно, но в таком случае метод `GetEnumerator()` должен быть, во-первых, публичным - а во-вторых, он должен возвращать не null

Comment: Как я понял, использование интерфейса IMyType, с абстрактным методом Method позволит избежать использования рефлексии?

Comment: @Garrus_En Да, так как вы знаете тип на этапе компиляции. И это не абстрактный метод, а сигнатура, абстрактные методы бывают в абстрактных классах и помечаются словом abstract. Но смысл схож.

Comment: @RuslanArtamonov, а как в случае с MyCollect : IEnumerable<IMyType>, IEnumerator   правильно реализовать generic интерфейс?

Comment: @RuslanArtamonov, у меня каша получается, работать без двух одинаковых GetEnumerator() класс не хочет, требует наличия обоих, а использует только дженерик

Comment: @Garrus_En Для начала предлагаю вообще отказаться от идеи реализации своей коллекции и использовать готовую, например `List<IMyType>`. Реализация собственной коллекции - дело редкое.